# Chef integration with CI for DEV and PROD deployments

Tags: continuous-integration, chef-infra

We have two environments, DEV and PROD. Each environment has 3 nodes:

- DEV

  - `devapp01` (Tomcat)
  - `devapp02` (Tomcat; identical to 01 and load-balanced)
  - `devdb01` (MySQL)
- PROD

  - `app01` (Tomcat)
  - `app02` (Tomcat; identical to 01 and load-balanced)
  - `db01` (MySQL)

The Tomcat instances serve WARs that are produced by a CI build.

We need the software stack on all DEV machines to be configured identically to those on PROD. We have set up a simple Chef server to manage configs on all nodes, and have created recipes for app and DB servers.

On the Chef server, we currently have an auto-update feature that runs every 30 minutes to check all nodes and make sure they're in synch with their respective recipes. The way our in-house "chef" (a sys admin) set everything up, there's a part of a recipe that does an existential check on Tomcat's `webapps` directory to determine whether an update should be performed or not. In other words, if Tomcat's webapp's directory has a WAR inside of it already, then when the auto-update runs every 30 mins, since `webapps` isn't empty, Chef won't go out to the CI server and pull in the new WAR.

To combat this, our chef cooked up a "**clean slate**" recipe that will first delete exploded WARs from Tomcat's webapps dir. So as long as that recipe executes first, TOMCAT_HOME/webapps will be executed before the Tomcat check; it then removes itself from the Chef runlist. His reasoning for this removal was that - in production - if we are
always deleting Tomcat's webapps dir then we will be redeploying prod nodes every 30 minutes.

So on DEV, we do want every CI build to produce a new WAR being deployed to our Tomcat instances (devapp01/02). In PROD, we want to manually kick off the deployment, which according to how this chef has configured everything, involves manually adding the **clean slate recipe** so that the CI server can deploy the new WAR.

I'm wondering how other people/teams have used CI and Chef in conjunction in the past, and if they ran into similar issues. My concrete question is: **how can we accomplish letting CI drive all the DEV deployments, but still make PROD deployments a manual process?**

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at CloudMunch for this as this is one of the scenarios that has been envisaged already there.

CloudMunch integrates natively into chef server and provides a manual workflow to allow deployment into staging or production environments.

*Disclaimer: I work at CloudMunch.*

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to have separate Chef organizations (or even servers) for dev and prod. This gives you strong separation by default. You CI pushes to dev, prod pushes are done purposefully.

Chef Inc is also working on [Policyfiles](https://blog.chef.io/2015/08/18/policyfiles-a-guided-tour/), which are an interesting replacement for Environments that shouldn't suffer from the same metadata/cookbook version leakage problems.